# Passing parameters from Delphi 5 to Delphi DLL XE

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi 5 application in the application code calls a function in the DLL, passing integer and string parameters, this works well when the DLL is called in a static way, when I try to dynamically change does not work.
which is the correct way to pass parameters to function dynamically?
the code is as follows

**main application**

```
  function Modulo_Pptos_Operacion(No_Orden : Integer; pathBD : string; PathBDConf :   String) : Integer ; stdcall;
 external 'LIB_Pptos_Oper.dll';

  Modulo_Pptos_Operacion(DmDatos.OrdenesNO_Orden.AsInteger,
   DmDatos.CiasPATHA.AsString, 'Alguna String');
```

**DLL**

```
  Modulo_Pptos_Operacion function (No_Orden: Integer; PathDB: AnsiString; PathDBConfig: AnsiString): Integer; StdCall;
```

**DYNAMIC CRASH**
main application

```
  type
    TDLLPpto = function(No_Orden : Integer; PathDB : AnsiString; PathDBConfig : AnsiString) : Integer;
  var
    DLLHandle: THandle;
    : TDLLPpto;

  PROCEDURE CALL
    DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('LIB_Pptos_Oper.dll');
    DLLHandle <> 0 then
   begin
     @DLLPpto := GetProcAddress(DLLHandle, 'Modulo_Pptos_Operacion');
   end;
  ;
```

which is the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of dynamically loaded dll you omitted `stdcall;` calling convention directive in the declaration of `TDLLPpto`. Still it is advisable to use `PAnsiChar` type to pass strings across executable boundaries.

Comment: Not only advisable, it's often subtly unstable if you don't.   Prepare for Random Badness.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably that you are mixing different runtimes and probably different heaps. Delphi strings are not valid interop types because their implementations vary from version to version.

In this case you can simply switch to using null-terminated strings, PAnsiChar.

Comment: Exactly.  AnsiString  is NEVER safe, even if you don't mix delphi versions, unless both the main EXE and the DLL use the shared memory (borlandmm.dll) memory manager.

Answer (score 1):

The layout of ansistring has changed with Delphi XE: now there is also a codepage field at negative offset and D5 does not have that. EG: strings from D5 and DXE are utterly incompatible. Thus you should use PAnsiChar or PWideChar in your interface, either zero terminated (Delphi strings are always zero terminated) of introduce an extra parameter with the length if the string might contain #$00 bytes.

Also: the different Delphi versions both have different memory managers. If a string is allocated by the main app and freed by the DLL (strings are reference counted) the pointer get's passed to the wrong memory manager which usually results in corrupted memory and thus nasty Access Violations etc.

Another solution is to use WideString; this is both in D5 en DXE equal to a COM BSTR stringtype and managed by the OS and not the Delphi memory manager. They are compatible. The only problem is: they are slow compared to the Delphi strings and are not ref counted.

In all: when using DLL interfaces, try to avoid string, use PAnsiChar or PWideChar, or WideString

Comment: `WideString` is an excellent choice also, one that I omitted in my answer. I doubt that performance of `WideString` vs `UnicodString/AnsiString` is relevant here.

Comment: @David: I doubt it also, but these answers are also read by others for their problems and usually this kind of information matters ;-).